# CSS background SVG animation strange behavior in Opera

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, opera

I have a problem with behavior of CSS background SVG animation in different browsers. It used to work perfectly few months ago (including Opera) but now it behaves strangely in Opera. It appears to work in other browsers.

How to fix it?

---

#### OPERA:

As you can see the spinner is jumping to the upper left corner.

[image: Opera]

### ----------------------------------

#### OTHER BROWSERS:

[image]

---

#### CODE:

```css
#spinner{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#343a40;
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='a' viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23a%7Banimation:faspin 2s infinite linear%7D%40keyframes faspin%7B0%25%7Btransform%3Arotate%280deg%29%7D100%25%7Btransform%3Arotate%28360deg%29%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M304 48c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48s-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48 48 21.49 48 48zm-48 368c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zm208-208c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zM96 256c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48S0 229.49 0 256s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48zm12.922 99.078c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.491-48-48-48zm294.156 0c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.49-48-48-48zM108.922 60.922c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.491-48-48-48z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:80%;
    background-position:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

#### HTML version of animation

```css
/*DEMO PURPOSE*/
body{background:#343a40}
svg{width:100px;height:100px}
```

```html
<svg id='a' viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <style>
        #a{animation:faspin 2s infinite linear}
        @keyframes faspin{
            0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}
            100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}
        }
    </style>
    <path fill='#fff' d='M304 48c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48s-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48 48 21.49 48 48zm-48 368c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zm208-208c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zM96 256c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48S0 229.49 0 256s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48zm12.922 99.078c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.491-48-48-48zm294.156 0c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.49-48-48-48zM108.922 60.922c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.491-48-48-48z'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Presumably you actually [want to be here](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/)

Comment: This was/is a bug in Opera 60 and Chrome 73, fixed in the next version: http://crbug.com/945609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of animating the svg #a I'm animating the path. In order to make it work I'm using `path{animation:faspin 2s infinite linear;transform-box: fill-box;transform-origin: 50% 50%;}`

```css
#spinner{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#343a40;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='a' viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E path%7Banimation:faspin 2s infinite linear;transform-box: fill-box;transform-origin: 50%25 50%25;%7D @keyframes faspin%7B 25%25%7Btransform:rotate(80deg)%7D 100%25%7Btransform:rotate(360deg)%7D %7D %3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='white' d='M304 48c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48s-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48 48 21.49 48 48zm-48 368c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zm208-208c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zM96 256c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48S0 229.49 0 256s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48zm12.922 99.078c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.491-48-48-48zm294.156 0c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.49-48-48-48zM108.922 60.922c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.491-48-48-48z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:80%;
    background-position:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

The SVG you are using for the background is now looking like this:

```css
body{background:black}

svg{width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg id='a' viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <style>
    path{animation:faspin 2s infinite linear;transform-box: fill-box;transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
    @keyframes faspin{
      25%{transform:rotate(80deg)}
      100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}
    }
    </style><path fill='white' d='M304 48c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48s-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48 48 21.49 48 48zm-48 368c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zm208-208c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.49-48-48-48zM96 256c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48S0 229.49 0 256s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48zm12.922 99.078c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.491-48-48-48zm294.156 0c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48c0-26.509-21.49-48-48-48zM108.922 60.922c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48 48-21.49 48-48-21.491-48-48-48z'/></svg>
```

I hope it helps.